# SQL string matching

Tags: mysql, sql, pattern-matching

I use a string for store the days of the week, something like this:
MTWTFSS. And if I search for MF (Monday and Friday) then the query must return all the strings that contain MF (for example: MWF, MTWTFS, MF,  and so on).

I don't know how to do this in SQL (MySQL).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `LIKE` with `%`-wildcard between the single characters:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%M%F%';
```

note that this will only work if the characters are in correct order - searching for `FM` instead of `MF` won't give you any result.
you'll also need to find a way to insert the `%`s to your search-term, but taht shouldn't be a big problem (sadly you havn't said wich programming-language you're using).

if the characters can be in random order, you'll have to built a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE
  column LIKE '%M%'
AND
  column LIKE '%F%'
[more ANDs per character];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE columnName LIKE '%MF%'
```

Learn more:

http://www.sqllike.com/

Comment: this wont match `MWF`, but should. the like-clause has to be `%M%F%` in my opinion.

Comment: @oezi: Probably if OP really meant that :)

Answer (score 2):

Can you not just say

```
SELECT * FROM blah WHERE weekday LIKE "%MF%"
```